# How to detect if a node contains significant information?

Tags: xslt

I need to find out how to detect if a node contains **significant** information.

The following example shows what is **not** considered "significant" information by me:

```
<node>
    <node1>&nbsp;</node1>
    </br></br>
    &nbsp;

    <node1>
        &nbsp;
        <node2></br>&nbsp;</node2>
        </br></br>
    </node1>
    <!--
    and so on...
    -->
</node>
```

This `<node>` is "**empty**" for me.

Comment: @Franci Penov, thank you for corrections.

Comment: But he didn't correct your malformed XML file!

Comment: Good question (+1). See my solution for an answer. Also, never ever post malformed XML documents. This is evil.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, Such structure gives out CMS. I cannot interfere and correct there yet. 
The content is brought by users and they there put all without analysis, and CMS does not clean dust as it is necessary.
I receive already ready XML and I can affect it only in small degree.

Comment: Don't call this "XML". And remove the "S" from your "CMS".

Comment: Because what you provided *is not XML*, it cannot be processed with *any* compliant XSLT processor! Just remove the XSLT tag from your question and ask it in "XML-junk".

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, Well, I will transfer your words to our developers.

Comment: I updated the solution -- now you have a one-liner that defines a variable as true() or false(), reflecting if the string value of the current node is "significant" or "insignificant".

Comment: Just to be REAL CLEAR the </br> tags are closures and do not close anything, thus the xml structure is inappropriate/invalid. They should be <br /> or should be <br></br> pairs

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss, Yes, I agree. The tag `<br>` is written not valid.

Comment: @kalininew, My code *always* works. I never post incomplete or untested code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is how to do it**:

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "text()
      [translate(normalize-space(), '&#160;','')
      = ''
      ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied to the following XML document (the one you provided was severely malformed -- non-well formed in numerous ways!!):

```
<!DOCTYPE node [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> ]>
<node>
    <node1>&nbsp;</node1>
    <br></br>
    &nbsp;

    <node1>
        &nbsp;
        <node2><br/>&nbsp;</node2>
        <br></br>
    </node1>
    <!--
    and so on...
    -->
</node>
```

**then the wanted result is produced**:

```
<node>
   <node1/>
   <br/>
   <node1>
      <node2>
         <br/>
      </node2>
      <br/>
   </node1><!--
    and so on...
    -->
</node>
```

**This technique can be generalized**:

*You can have all whetespace-characters in an xsl:variable, then simply override the identity rule with this template*:

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vwhiteSpace" select="' &#x9;&#xA;&#xD;&nbsp;'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:if test="translate(., $vwhiteSpace,'') != ''">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**And you can specify all additional characters you consider "white-space" in `$vwhiteSpace`**

**Update**: The OP indicated in a comment that he actually wants to see if a "node" is significant or not -- not to "clean a node".

The solution to this is already contained in my solution to the initial problem:

```
  <xsl:variable name="vIsSignificant" select=
     "translate(., $vwhiteSpace,'') != ''"/>
```

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, I have badly explained a problem. It is necessary to answer "yes" or there is no"on a question" this node contains the significant information "? Your decision "cleans" knot. I want check the importance of the node, instead of cleaning is necessary to me.

Comment: @kalininew, My code *always* works. I never post incomplete or untested code.

Comment: Yes, it is the truth. Thanks you for it.